# Two SoapClient requests for two different thirdparty WSDL services, one works, the other doesn't

Tags: php, web-services, security, wsdl, tls1.2

In both cases the respective WSDL loads in Firefox and shows "Safe connection". The PHP version is 5.6.22, it means that by default PHP will verify that the connection is secure (opposite to the behavior of PHP 5.5.x and prior http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php). The idea is to precisely perform secure connections, both cases are done to be secure, the proper verifications are being made implicitly.

---

**Need this case to work (Case A):**

```
$wsdl = 'https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL';
$entity_loader_status_old = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$SoapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$seed = $SoapClient -> getSeed();
libxml_disable_entity_loader($entity_loader_status_old);
var_dump($seed);
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL"
 in /path/to/script.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/script.php(3): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://palena....')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/script.php on line 3
```

---

**This example case works (Case B):**

```
$wsdl = 'https://www.lb.lt/webservices/ExchangeRates/ExchangeRates.asmx?WSDL';
$entity_loader_status_old = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$SoapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$exchangeRate = $SoapClient -> getExchangeRate();
libxml_disable_entity_loader($entity_loader_status_old);
var_dump($exchangeRate);
```

Dump:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["getExchangeRateResult"]=> string(2) "-1" }
```

Note: this case is auxiliar, only for demonstration.

---

The **Case A** worked for months (always PHP 5.6.x), only two days ago it stopped working and throwing the error, yet no code has been changed. The date of failure is close to the *Valid-From* date of the certificate of the webservice (12 dec 2016 to 14 dec 2017), looks like the server just renewed its certificate (saw the dates in the details of the certificate by loading the WSDL address in a browser), it is very likely that this has everything to do with the problem.

Apparently, to be trusted by the client, the renewed certificate requires a specific intermediate certificate that is poorly diffused, so the intermediate certificate has to be found and added to the bundle of trusted intermediate certificates. To do that, the intermediate certificate was found, and by using its download address, the next three lines were executed in the client:

```
wget http://symantec.tbs-certificats.com/Symantec_Class_3_EV_SSL_CA_G3.crt
cp Symantec_Class_3_EV_SSL_CA_G3.crt
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors update-ca-trust
```

At some extent it seems to have worked, because now an error is not producing from line 3(`SoapClient`), but from line 4(`getSeed`):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host
 in /path/to/script.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://palena....', '', 1, 0)
#1 /path/to/script.php(4): SoapClient->__call('getSeed', Array)
#2 /path/to/script.php(4): SoapClient->getSeed()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/script.php on line 4
```

---

**Case A** works when disabling the secure connection verification (but that's not the solution because it breaks the security):

```
$wsdl = 'https://palena.sii.cl/DTEWS/CrSeed.jws?WSDL';
$entity_loader_status_old = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$SoapClient = new SoapClient(
    $wsdl
    , [
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create([
            'ssl' => [
                'verify_peer' => false,
            ],
        ]),
    ]
);
$seed = $SoapClient -> getSeed();
libxml_disable_entity_loader($entity_loader_status_old);
var_dump($seed);
```

Dump:

```
string(219) "00436612495400"
```

---

**Why Case A doesn't work with security verification and how to fix it?**

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP secure connection with WSDL service breaks after server renewed certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175867/php-secure-connection-with-wsdl-service-breaks-after-server-renewed-certificate) (answered)

Answer (score 0):

For me case B also works :

It retuns this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SII:RESPUESTA xmlns:SII="http://www.sii.cl/XMLSchema">
<SII:RESP_BODY>
<SEMILLA>004361002032</SEMILLA></SII:RESP_BODY>
<SII:RESP_HDR><ESTADO>00</ESTADO></SII:RESP_HDR>
</SII:RESPUESTA>
```

I m using php version 5.5.9

Comment: With or without certificate verification?

Comment: I just ran your code and it gaves me the above result:

Comment: I presented two codes for each case, the difference was just that one has explicit certificate verification. Now I tryed disabling certificate verification and it worked, I think you tested the code that doesn't verify certificate in php older than 5.6 (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php). I think that if you try the code that does explicitly verify the certificate then you will get the error, because you have PHP 5.5.